# Refreshing php script inside a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am currently using the following script to refresh my messages.php in a div with a timeinterval of 60 seconds.

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
setInterval("getResult()",60000);
});
function getResult(){   
jQuery.post("messages.php",function( data ) {
    jQuery("#msgs").html(data);
});
}
</script>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
```

My current problem is that the echo of the php file displays for the first time after the 60 seconds passed. Then it refreshes every 60 seconds. 
I need to get the code to load at the start of launching the page.

Comment: so, what you already achieve? where u stuck?

Comment: `jQuery(getResult);`would call it once document is ready. FYI, this is preferred syntax: `setInterval(getResult, 60000);` avoiding string evaluation

Comment: just add getResult(); BEFORE your setInterval, so that it will be executed once and, then, executed each 60 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Call getResult() on DOM Ready as well

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
getResult();
setInterval("getResult()",60000);
});
function getResult(){   
jQuery.post("messages.php",function( data ) {
    jQuery("#msgs").html(data);
});
}
</script>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
```

Comment: missing semicolon after getResult().

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a setTimeout every time:

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function() {
    function getResult() {
       $('#msgs').load('messages.php', {});
       setTimeout(getResult, 60000);
    }

    getResult();
}
</script>
<div id="msgs"></div>
```

Alternative with re-fire in the callback (suggestion of A. Wolff, in case messages.php takes long to complete):

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function() {
    function getResult() {
       $('#msgs').load('messages.php', {}, function() {
           setTimeout(getResult, 60000);
       });
    }

    getResult();
}
</script>
<div id="msgs"></div>
```

Comment: Good call on passing data to load method and using a timeout, even i'd use the complete load method callback, just in case the request takes more than 60 sec to complete

Comment: Nice idea. I'll add an alternative based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data on page load, call `getResult()` on DOM ready event as shown below :-

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
  getResult();  //it will get data as soon as page is loaded.
  setInterval("getResult()",60000); // it will refresh #msgs after every 1 min.
});
function getResult(){   
  jQuery.post("messages.php",function( data ) {
    jQuery("#msgs").html(data);
  });
}
</script>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery().ready(function(){
   getResult();
   setInterval("getResult()",60000);
});
function getResult(){   
jQuery.post("messages.php",function( data ) {
    jQuery("#msgs").html(data);
});
}
</script>
<div id="msgs">
</div>
```

Use this code..